# Total number of ways to distribute N indistinguishable objects into K distinguishable boxes such that no box contains more than P objects?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say there are 3 objects and 3 boxes and no box can contain more than 2 objects then the answer will be 7:
`{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2} and {1, 2, 0}`
How do I solve it for any general value of N, K and P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box $i$ will contain $P_i$ objects where $0 \leq P_i \leq P$ ($i=1,\cdots,K$) & we require $\sum_{i=1}^{K} P_i =N$.

A formula for this is given by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
[x^N]: (1+x+ \cdots +x^P)^K.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Sorry but what does \begin{eqnarray*}
[x^N]: 
\end{eqnarray*} 
in \begin{eqnarray*}
[x^N]: (1+x+ \cdots +x^P)^K.
\end{eqnarray*} mean?
are you referring to coefficient of \begin{eqnarray*}
x^N: 
\end{eqnarray*} ?

Comment: $[x^N]:f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^N$ in the expansion of the function $f$.

Comment: Thanks Donald that works.

Comment: By the way If you can explain how to derive this or atleast what should I learn in order to derive this.

Comment: I am reading/ trying to get my head around this at the moment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Answer (score 0):

The other approach is to use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

For the example you gave, it would be $\binom{5}{2} - \binom31\binom{2}{2} = 7$

The general formula for $N$ objects, $K$ boxes and a max of $P$ in each box would be

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{N}{K}\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom Nj\binom{N-j(P+1)+K-1}{K-1}\;
$$

For the example you gave, $\lfloor\frac{N}{K}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{3}{2}\rfloor = 1$,

so $\binom 30 \binom{3-0(2+1)+3-1}{3-1} - \binom31\binom{3-1(2+1)+3-1}{3-1}= \binom 52 - 3\binom 22 = 7$

Comment: Thank you true blue anil. Sorry but with the reputation I currently have can not upvote your answer.

Comment: As long as it is of use, all good !